# Regular expression for 1-31

Tags: regex

I'd like to make a reglar expression which checks date digit e.g. 1 through 31.
I think it has three patterns : `[0-9]`, `[12][0-9]`, `3[01]`.

But I don't know how to make them as one regex with |(or) operator.

Anybody has idea for this?

Comment: You know you need to use the `|` operator, but have you tried anything with it yourself?

Comment: `[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]`?

Comment: I did it on the https://regex101.com/ page. But it didn't work.

Comment: Download Expresso, it's a free tool will help you with the Regex. Your date digit it's not clear did you mean something like ddmmyyyy ?

Comment: http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])

Hope this answer your question

Comment: I tried to write your expression on the  regex101.com page and try 32. But it said two matches.

Comment: Thanks. it works.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and a group to make the pattern local. Just use a `|` within the capture group `(a|b)` or non-capturing group `(?:a|b)`:

```
([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```